# Is there a way I can get the Gatling "Report ID"?

Tags: scala, gatling

When Gatling creates a test report, it names the report directories as `{{simulationId}}-{{someLongNumberId}}` (example - `single_user_test-1507218111111`)

Is there a way I can get this number after load test has completed (in a 'after' hook maybe?)

The reason I want to do this is to create path to get `js/stats.json` file in test reports folder and get `minResponseTime, maxResponseTime, meanResponseTime` objects.

I'm new to scala/gatling so useful links are welcome!

Comment: Well you could just get the folder that was created most recently.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done right now while I was waiting if someone knows an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're talking about is:

```
scala> System.currentTimeMillis
res1: Long = 1508321556008
```

The last sentence printed in the standard output, is:

```
Reports generated in 0s.
Please open the following file: /Users/nicolas/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.3.0/results/basicsimulation-1508321476222/index.html
```

Can't you parse that?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks!
I guess I could parse it, but as of right now i'm rolling with the solution of getting  the folder that was created most recently.